# Intellij new import goes to same line as the previous imported class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: import goes to same line as the previous import]

hi guys

im using IntelliJ 2019.3.2 , i've been searching on how i can change the way new import added in my code (no luck) already checked the Code Style area , as you guys can see my new imported class goes to same line as the previous imported class..

Comment: Do you use any custom plugins?

Answer (score 2):

In my *specific* case it was happening because I had disabled InteliJ IDEA's formatter:

[image: Settings | Editor | Code Style | Formatter tab]

(I added the * in the "Do not format" text box).

Settings | Editor | Code Style | Formatter tab

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case is happened because I had old an codestyle plugin. Updating and restarting IntelliJ fixed it.